# select model B with model A column name condition in laravel model

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have two models with different name and columns but the purpose/data of the two models is the same, namely, it contains the employee's name, here the model

Employee

| name | code | country | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | A1 | USA | NYC |
| Doe | A2 | USA | LA |

New_Employee

| v_fullname | v_code | v_country | v_city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | ZZ1 | USA | LS |
| Zuc | FF2 | USA | LS |

as you can see the column name is different but the purpose is identical. I want to select data from `New_Employee` but use column name from `Employee`, so the query will look like this

```
SELECT v_fullname as name, v_code as code, v_country as country, v_city as city
FROM New_Employee
WHERE name = 'Mark'
```

Sorry if my explanation is hard to understand, but here's the code I have tried

SyncEmployee model (this model is like a bridge connecting employee and new_employee model)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Employee;
use App\Models\NewEmployee;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SyncEmployee extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $connection = 'mysql_2';

    public const TABLE_NAME = 'new_employee';

    public function index()
    {
        $data = NewEmployee::select('v_fullname as name, v_code as code, v_country as country, v_city as city')->get();
        return view('view_name', compact('data'));
    }

}
```

I thought with that code when I call `SyncEmployee::where('code', '=', 'ZZ1')` from controller, the result will

| name | code | country | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | ZZ1 | USA | LS |

*The data is from `New_Employee` but the column name using `Employee`

Comment: And you fail to explain the most important part: what is wrong with it, what is not working...

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt to use the ability to hide or append attributes at serialization to do most of the work for you. You would need to define accessors and mutators and define what is 'hidden' and 'appended' for serialization:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;

class NewEmployee extends Model
{
    ...

    protected $table = 'new_employee';

    protected $hidden = [
        ...
        'v_fullname',
        'v_code',
        'v_country',
        'v_city',
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        ...
        'name',
        'code',
        'country',
        'city',
    ];

    protected function name(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn () => $this->attributes['v_fullname'] ?? null,
            set: fn ($v) => $this->attributes['v_fullname'] = $v
        );
    }
    
    ...
}
```

If you are not using the Model's data after serialization you can still access these fields:

```
// will hit the accessor
$newEmployee->code;

// will hit the mutator
$newEmployee->code = 'blah';
```

[Laravel 9.x Docs - Eloquent: Mutators and Casting - Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

[Laravel 9.x Docs - Eloquent: Serialization - Hiding Attributes From JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)

[Laravel 9.x Docs - Eloquent: Serialization - Appending Values to JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

Comment: what if i use Model::where('column', '=', 'xxxx'), it's still hit the mutator? or the original?

Comment: once you fetch data from the model make use of collection. eg: collect($modelData)->where('code','=','xxxx')->first();